# Каким образом можно намеренно повредить PDF файл с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

У меня есть обычный\работающий PDF-файл который мне нужно повредить при определённых условиях с помощью JavaScript. То есть мне нужно чтобы файл был читаем и рабочим пока не случились определённые условия(например наступила какая-либо дата). При совершении этих условий, встроенный скрипт бы повреждал файл и Adobe Acrobat выдавал ошибку при его открытии, сообщая о невозможности его чтения. Скажите, каким образом возможно это сделать? Для внедрения скриптов в файл использовал вот этот код на Python

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

output = PdfWriter()
ipdf = PdfReader(open('blank.pdf', 'rb'))

for i in range(len(ipdf.pages)):
    page = ipdf.pages[i]
    output.add_page(page)

with open('new.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    output.add_js("app.alert(\"Startup\");")
    output.write(f)
```

Comment: Да, но его можно будет открыть просмоторщиком без скриптов

Comment: @eri Ну, думаю это приемлемо. Мне самое главное-узнать каким образом это сделать, в JavaScript я к сожалению не силён

Comment: А не проще просто подготовить битый файл? И возвращать его при каком либо условии. Ибо если он все равно битым не откроется, то и нет необходимости его ломать на лету

Comment: @MrYogurt К сожалению требуется скрипт именно повреждения файла. К тому же, это точно можно реализовать в одном документе?

Comment: С помощью какой нибудь библиотеки, например [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF).

Comment: @lamedude29 можно еще воспользоваться сервисом corrupt-a-file точка net, просто кидать ему файл и получать на него ссылку. Реализация довольно простая, хотя и не факт, что надежная.